# Does the Spring `SavedRequest` include any cleanup logic to avoid redirect loops or similar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using the `SavedRequest` to redirect the user to the originally requested URL after login.

I get the url like this:

```
public String requestedUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
        if (savedRequest != null) {
            return savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        }
        return "";
}
```

I wonder if it is worth to check on that URL, if for example

- the base-path is corresponding to the configured application base path (for security reasons)
- the path is not redirecting to /login or some other urls which might cause an infinite redirect loop

Does the `SavedRequest` do any cleanup similar to this? If yes, which exactly?

Comment: Update: I've experience a redirect loop in relation to this but could not reproduce it, generally it seems the loginUrl "/login" does not get saved in the savedRequest. Not sure. I've temporary added safety checks and waiting for a credible answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer and is based on a survey of the code because I'm curious. :3**

Let me begin by saying that it would be useful to know how you've configured Spring Security in your project to actually get the root of your problem. As you trace up from `SavedRequest` to see how it's used in Spring Security a lot of possible avenues open up regarding how everything is wired up and configured at the beginning.

As the preceding notes, the code directly adjacent to `SavedRequest` itself is so simple that it is generally unrelated to the root of your problem. Your question's focus could be broadened: "Does Spring Security avoid redirect loops to /login when applying SavedRequests?"

I think the docs [10.1.4 Request Matching and HttpFirewall](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching) do address your question regarding the base path:

> The Servlet Specification defines several properties for the HttpServletRequest which are accessible via getter methods, and which we might want to match against. These are the contextPath, servletPath, pathInfo and queryString. **Spring Security is only interested in securing paths within the application, so the contextPath is ignored.**

Emphasis mine.

In a default configuration it appears that [`DefaultSavedRequest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.java) will be the implementation of [`SavedRequest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/SavedRequest.java) in use according to [`HttpSessionRequestCache`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/HttpSessionRequestCache.java).

`DefaultSavedRequest` has not undergone any extensive [changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commits/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.java) since you originally asked your question.

Establishing that, we can say that the implementation of the class is fairly straightforward, is very bean-like and limits itself to saving the request as presented. It performs no analysis during construction, other than to exclude certain headers ("Skip If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match header").

```java
public DefaultSavedRequest(HttpServletRequest request, PortResolver portResolver) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "Request required");
    Assert.notNull(portResolver, "PortResolver required");

    // Cookies
    addCookies(request.getCookies());

    // Headers
    Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();

    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = names.nextElement();
        // Skip If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match header. SEC-1412, SEC-1624.
        if (HEADER_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE.equalsIgnoreCase(name)
                || HEADER_IF_NONE_MATCH.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            continue;
        }
        Enumeration<String> values = request.getHeaders(name);

        while (values.hasMoreElements()) {
            this.addHeader(name, values.nextElement());
        }
    }

    // Locales
    addLocales(request.getLocales());

    // Parameters
    addParameters(request.getParameterMap());

    // Primitives
    this.method = request.getMethod();
    this.pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
    this.queryString = request.getQueryString();
    this.requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    this.serverPort = portResolver.getServerPort(request);
    this.requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    this.scheme = request.getScheme();
    this.serverName = request.getServerName();
    this.contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    this.servletPath = request.getServletPath();
}
```

`addCookies`, `addHeader`, `addLocales` and `addParameters` are similarly simple. This class doesn't resolve requests to guard against infinite redirects or even check its base path.

Therefore we'll cast the net further to find another suspect. Next up is [`HttpSessionRequestCache`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/HttpSessionRequestCache.java). The bean can be created in a variety of ways based on your usage of Spring Security so things kind of spiral out from there [`HttpConfigurationBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/HttpConfigurationBuilder.java) / [`HttpSecurity`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java) / [`RequestCacheConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/RequestCacheConfigurer.java); an expert+more information from you would indeed be welcome!